# Transform blocks to select box

Tags: xslt

please, help to transform blocks

```
<div id="category-list">
  <div class="category"><a href="/link-1">Sample Category</a></div>
  <div class="category"><a href="/link-2">Another Sample Category</a></div>
</div>
```

to select box (I will add javascript for links working myself)

```
<select>
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="/link-1">Sample Category</option>
    <option value="/link-2">Another Sample Category</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="div[@id = 'category-list']">
  <select>
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </select>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@class = 'category']/a[@href]">
  <option value="{@href}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></option>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: User3497585 - the usual thank you on Stackoverflow is to accept and/or upvote the answer. Thx comments are appreciated but not the full set of actions